# Position for scaled sprites is always the same - Unity (What Am I doing wrong?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First of all, I'm new to Unity and obviously I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what.

Take a look at the image below. There are three balls. The biggest one is the original size (imported) and the other two are scaled.

I wrote a code and gave these balls a linear force toward right edge of the camera. Camera size is 10 (which is 5 each way). When it reaches the edge it should bounce back to the left camera edge. It works but only the original one is bounced when it reaches the edge (other balls are bounced too at the same time, but they shouldn't because they haven't reached the edge).

All balls have the same position, but two are scaled and are bounced from "the air - check the image").

[image]

Code for changing direction is in the Update function. It looks like this:

```
if (rigidBody.transform.position.x > 5)
        {

            rigidBody.AddForce(new Vector2(-60,0));


        }
```

I appreciate all help.

Comment: But you are checking only the position (position will be the same no matter the scale) so they will move at the same position. Their center is in the same spot.

Comment: The above. You need to check the edge of the ball (left and right of course). Or you could change this to work with `OnCollisionEnter` and have colliders at the edge of the screen.

Comment: You need to work through all the really basic Unity tutorials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue I see is that your code only checks the position to make the balls rebound. The position is **probably** measured at the center of the images (check this out!), so you have to take into consideration the width of each ball - actually, from the center, half the width.

To check if the position plus half width of the image has arrived to the limit you can use *renderer.bounds.size* as in:

```
if ((transform.position.x + renderer.bounds.size.x/2) > 5)
    {
        //change directions
        //do something else...
    }
```

Put in another words, the smaller the size of the ball, the more the x position has to grow to get to the limit, and then you make them rebound.

I strongly encourage, however, a different approach to prevent having everything *hardcoded*. Just suppose you change your camera size, you would have to rewrite everything again!
I would put colliders on both sides of the camera limits, and when your balls collide with them set an `OnCollisionEnter` function that makes them change directions. That is a little off course from your question, so I'll leave it there. 
Good luck!